# How to set multi value to autocomplete component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need  to set multi selected value to autocomplete in reactjs. I'm using Material-UI components in my project.

[image]

F.e you can see above. First data is coming first user and second data is coming from another user. I want to fill in the value like that. Then, user can remove selected values or add new values.

If you can do it with dummy data, I can use with data from database. All i need how to do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 500,
    '& > * + *': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  },
}));


  export default function Multi({callbackFromMultiSelect,reference,favBooks}) {
  const classes = useStyles();


  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={favBooks}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => (option.name)}
        // onClick={()=>alert('test')}
        onChange={(event, value) =>callbackFromMultiSelect({value:value,reference:reference})}
        // defaultValue={[top100Films[1]]}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="favBooks"
            placeholder="favBooks"
          />
        )}
      />
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my parent component

```
import React from 'react'
import AutoCompleteTest from './AutoComplete'

export const Test = () => {
  const callbackFromMultiSelect = (item) => {
    console.log(item)
  }

  const favBooks=[
    {name:"LOTR",from:"a",to:"a"},
    {name:"GOT",from:"b",to:"b"},
    {name:"HP",from:"c",to:"c"}
  ]

  return (
    <div className={'mainStore'}>
      Test
      <AutoCompleteTest callbackFromMultiSelect={callbackFromMultiSelect} reference={'test'} favBooks={favBooks}/>
      <br />
      <AutoCompleteTest callbackFromMultiSelect={callbackFromMultiSelect} reference={'test'} favBooks={favBooks}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: you could reproduce this on codesandbox so others will catch up more easily

Answer (score 0):

I've made a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-saha-gor3s?file=/src/App.js

You basicly have to make the component a controlled component.
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground

You can do this by using the 'getOptionSelected' prop